# How to run some cmd commands in all network clients?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, administration

I have administrator rule on my network (running windows server 2003). How I can run some (4 or 5) cmd commands on all clients. I have heard it is done via active dorectory, but How?

Comment: You want to execute remote commands on these computers? If so, have a look here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: It seems to be a great program, but does it use only computer names?